# NodeJS Check type of exception

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, error-handling

I'm sending JSON via a socket connection and would like to check if the JSON received is complete. If I try parsing incomplete JSON I do get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` but I don't know how to check for just that Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straigh forward way would be using `try ... catch` and checking `name` and `message` of the exception. Of course there may be different messages for different error scenarios, but if you only need that specific error, this should work:

```js
console.log("Incomplete JSON string");
try { 
  var x = JSON.parse(`{ "a": `); 
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name === "SyntaxError" && e.message === "Unexpected end of JSON input") {
    console.log("incomplete json");
  } else {
    console.log(e.name, e.message); 
  }
}

console.log("\nInvalid JSON synax");
try { 
  var x = JSON.parse(`{ "a":, `); 
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name === "SyntaxError" && e.message === "Unexpected end of JSON input") {
    console.log("incomplete json");
  } else {
    console.log(e.name, e.message); 
  }
}
```

But be aware, that the JSON parser only throws the first error it encounters. Ie, if it finds some invalid syntax within the JSON string, it will never throw an `"Unexpected end of JSON input"` even if the string is indeed incomplete, as can be seen in the second example